# In SharePoint Online Infopath Form can't get User Profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, user-profile, user-profile-property

After migrating a InfoPath form in SP online, i faced the issue as can't get user profile of SP user. As the rest and soap is not supported in SP online Infopath form, what are the alternatives to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs because loopback protection is enabled in the SharePoint Online environment. Loopback protection must be disabled for InfoPath forms to be able to connect to a SharePoint Online web service. This works only when loopback protection is disabled. For security reasons, loopback protection is always enabled in SharePoint Online. This is a known limitation of InfoPath forms in the Office 365 SharePoint Online

As a work around you can create a data connection to the User Information List and get the details of any user.

- Create the Data Connection to the User Information List

[image]

- Connect to the User Info List
  [image]
- Select the User Properties
  [image]
- In the Form Query the User Info List
  [image]
- Select the required properties

[image]

**More Details**

[Connect to User Information List](http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/infopath-user-information-list/)

[SP Online Infopath User Profile Workaround](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sharepoint-online-infopath-form-user-profile-limitation-and-workaround-21647.aspx)