# Infopath forms migrated to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath, powerapp, infopath-form

Currently we are migrating SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online .

Issue is , in SharePoint 2007 we have lots of infopath forms . Few forms have repetitive form groups . Now I am stuck how to implement the same in production . Please suggest idea .

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath still works and is still currently supported in SharePoint online. So the simple, short term answer is to move the forms.

One caveat with the above is that online doesn't support forms with code, so if a developer customized the forms with visual studio, you're out of luck. Another difficulty is using the user profile service from infopath, which is a popular option on-prem, but not supported online. You can read about this issue, as well as the popular workaround, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222570/in-sharepoint-online-infopath-form-cant-get-user-profile).

As for PowerApps, I wish you the best. InfoPath and PowerApps were designed for different purposes. While PowerApps, of course, can create forms, it's challenging to create forms that look and behave in a similar way to the infopath forms. Not to mention that powerapps is slower, buggier, and has a steeper learning curve than infopath.

Personally, I'd migrate the InfoPath forms and run them as-is. I'd also start ramping up on PowerApps, and use PowerApps for any new forms. Then, start prioritizing which infopath forms are good candidates for PowerApps, and start chipping through them.

Before you get too far with PowerApps, make sure you understand the issues around form ownership, version control, migrating forms from dev to prod, updating apps that are already in prod, etc., before you get too far into it.

edit: On repetitive form groups: learn how to use "galleries" in powerapps, which is equivalent to a repeating section. Also, a single app can connect to multiple sources, so you could connect to one list for the parent row, and another list for the child rows. Or, look into the "common data service", which is a type of online database that is part of powerapps and which supports tables with one-to-many relationships, which could be used in place of Sharepoint lists.